# How to have a different logo on mobile view wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

How can I change my logo to another smaller image when my website is being viewed on a mobile or tablet and hide the logo used on desktop browsers?

Using Wordpress, genesis framework and a child theme.

http://www.caspercreations.ie

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show meanigful code?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that solved my original problem:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.site-title a {
    background: transparent url("http://caspercreations.ie/awning1logomobile.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

}

}

@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .site-title a {
        background: transparent url("http://caspercreations.ie/awning1logotablet.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
        display: block;
    }
}

And here is how the gap between the logo and main contained was fixed:

```
.header-full-width.header-image .site-title a {
background-position: center bottom !important;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. If your logo is background image then use the following CSS:

   ```
   @media (max-width: 480px){
       .logo a { background: url('path-to-mobile-logo') no-repeat 0 0; }
   }
   ```
2. If your logo is an `img` tag then use the following structure:

Html:

```
<a class="logo">
    <img src="desktop-logo" alt="" class="logo-img logo-img-desktop">
    <img src="tablet-logo" alt="" class="logo-img logo-img-tablet">
    <img src="mobile-logo" alt="" class="logo-img logo-img-mobile">
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.logo-img { display: none; }

@media (min-width: 1025px){
    .logo-img-desktop { display: block; }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){
    .logo-img-tablet { display: block; }
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){
    .logo-img-mobile { display: block; }
}
```

Comment: This worked but how do I get rid of the gap underneath the logo so it's touching the main container?

Comment: `@media (max-width: 480px) {
 .site-title a {
  background: transparent url("http://caspercreations.ie/awning1logomobile.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
 }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
 .site-title a {
  background: transparent url("http://caspercreations.ie/awning1logotablet.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
 }
}`

Comment: Please include all of your code - Html and CSS, in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this precise selector:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header-image .site-title > a {
     background-image: url('images/your-mobile-logo.png');
  }
}
```